# javascript - Is there a way to upload and preview image on div (replace background-image) without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, image

I have a div (box) with default background-image. I want to allow users to upload image and preview in the box by replacing the background-image without refreshing the page. Thanks in advance. Below are my codes:

CSS:

```
#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.45);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
    background-image: url('../images/Default_Img.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
#overlay {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 45px 0 66px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

#box:hover #overlay {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

ASP:

```
<div id="box">
     <div id="overlay">
           <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpload" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" ><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload</asp:LinkButton>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= btnUpload.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
                $('#<%= fileUpload.ClientID %>').click();
                return false;
            });
        });

function readURL(input) {
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
         // what to do here to get image url and replace background-image?
     }
```

Comment: Upload the file with AJAX.

Comment: You just want to upload file? or want to preview only?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
    // call ajax here to uplaod the image
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
      <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
      <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of  for the purpose..

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"></canvas>
  <input id="fileupload" type="file"  placeholder="" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" />
```

Try this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[type=file]").change(function(e){
var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) {

    var img = new Image();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    img.onload = function () {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
});
});
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/knL5n95r/2/